# Kubernetes - login to kubernetes dashboard issue

Tags: kubernetes

So I'm trying to bring up my kubernetes dashboard (remote server) but I'm having issues.  How do I resolve this issue?

1. using https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.3/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml

2. Created a ServiceAccount

> kubectl create serviceaccount dashboard-admin-sa

3. Created an RBAC profile

> kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin-sa --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard-admin-sa

When I load the page I get this not the kubernetes dashboard

```
{
  "paths": [
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/log",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/livez",
    "/livez/etcd",
    "/livez/log",
    "/livez/ping",
    "/livez/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/livez/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/livez/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/readyz",
    "/readyz/etcd",
    "/readyz/log",
    "/readyz/ping",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/readyz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/readyz/shutdown",
    "/version"
  ]
}
```

**Details:**

> kubectl config view

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://100.xx.xx.x27:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

> kubectl get svc --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  7h19m
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   7h19m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.110.162.231   <none>        8000/TCP                 84m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.104.136.25    <none>        443/TCP                  84m
```

> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-jk8ql                                 1/1     Running   1          7h27m
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-wxsnf                                 1/1     Running   1          7h27m
kube-system            etcd-ip-100-xx-xx-x27                      1/1     Running   1          7h28m
kube-system            kube-apiserver-ip-100-xx-xx-x27            1/1     Running   1          7h28m
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-ip-100-xx-xx-x27   1/1     Running   1          7h28m
kube-system            kube-proxy-vbddf                                         1/1     Running   1          7h27m
kube-system            kube-scheduler-ip-100-xx-xx-x27            1/1     Running   1          7h28m
kube-system            weave-net-cfk2m                                          2/2     Running   3          7h27m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-6b4884c9d5-fwljp               1/1     Running   0          93m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-7f99b75bf4-x2hpq                    1/1     Running   0          93m
```

Comment: how are you accessing the dashboard? kubectl proxy? Share logs from kubernetes-dashboard pods

Comment: though the web browser https://100.xx.xx.x27:6443/ui.  Fairly new too kubernetes.  How do i share the kubernetes-dashboard pods logs?

Comment: add output of kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-7f99b75bf4-x2hpq -n kube-system. How kubernetes is deployed..minikube or something else?

Comment: kubernetes-dashboard-7f99b75bf4-x2hpq -n kube-system results in:
bash: kubernetes-dashboard-7f99b75bf4-x2hpq: command not found. It's not using minikube.  and used this article to set it up https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kubernetes-1-7-centos7-rhel7/

Comment: then used the above instructions to setup the dashboard

Comment: Add output of `kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-7f99b75bf4-x2hpq -n kube-system`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the really good guide which i would suggest to follow for setting up kubernetes dashaboard - https://jhooq.com/setting-up-kubernetes-dashboard/#kubernetes-dashboard-local-cluster

But what i see here is -

1. Keep the `kubectl proxy` running otherwise you will not be able to access the dashboard and it might result in http 404
2. Also check the validity of the token.
3. Check the service account, here is what i used for service account

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
EOF
```

4. ClusterRoleBinding

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
EOF
```

I hope it should solve your issue. If not then please check the guide and compare your steps which you did while setting up the dashboard

Comment: Thank you for sharing this article!  The only aspect of it that i don't see is if you are using it remotely and not locally.  Is there a way to add that to the article if you are trying to make it into a production environment.

Comment: Is kubectl proxy a service that must be running to access the dashboard remotely or just locally?

Comment: kubectl proxy should be running whether you access the dashboard remotely or locally.

Comment: Rahul, thanks for sharing and point out those items.  Could you possibly add a setup to just access the kubernetes install without google cloud service integration?  essentially login to kubernetes dashboard without Google cloud service?  thanks